# How do you calculate the capacity of a slice in the Sort-Tile-Recursive (STR) algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I'm having trouble understanding a part of the Sort-Tile-Recursive algorithm ([PDF link](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~mln/ltrs-pdfs/icase-1997-14.pdf)), located on page 6.

> [...] Determine the number of leaf level pages $P = \lceil r/n \rceil$ and let $S = \lceil \sqrt P \rceil$. Sort the rectangles by $x$-coordinate and partition them into $S$ vertical slices. A slice consists of a run of $S \cdot n$ consecutive rectangles from the sorted list. Note that the last slice may contain fewer than $S \cdot n$ rectangles. [...]

Consider a collection of $r = 101$ rectangles, using leaf capacity $n = 10$. I determine the number of leaf level pages $P = 11$ and the number of vertical slices $S = 4$. If I interpret the text correctly, this means a slice should consist of 40 rectangles, except the last one which can have less rectangles.
But this means that the slices contain 40, 40, 21 and 0 rectangles. This doesn't look like the intended result to me, so am I misinterpreting the text?

An existing implementation I'm looking at calculates the slice capacity as $ \lceil r / S \rceil$, so in this example it would be 26. That means the slices contain 26, 26, 26 and 23 slices, a more reasonable result I think.